# What is happening in the "emit" method of this class?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code from https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-create-your-own-event-emitter-in-javascript-fbd5db2447c4. I cannot understand what is going on within the "emit" method. Why is the constant being created and how does the forEach method apply a function to a function?

```
class MyEventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        this._events = {};
    }

    on(name, listener) {
        if (!this._events[name]) {
            this._events[name] = [];
        }

        this._events[name].push(listener);
    }

    removeListener(name, listenerToRemove) {
        if (!this._events[name]) {
            throw new Error(`Can't remove a listener. Event "${name}" doesn't exits.`);
        }

        const filterListeners = (listener) => listener !== listenerToRemove;

        this._events[name] = this._events[name].filter(filterListeners);
    }

    emit(name, data) {
        if (!this._events[name]) {
            throw new Error(`Can't emit an event. Event "${name}" doesn't exits.`);
        }

        const fireCallbacks = (callback) => callback(data);
      
        this._events[name].forEach(fireCallbacks);
        console.log(this._events[name]);
        

      
    }
}

// Create an instance:

const myEventEmitter = new MyEventEmitter();
console.log(myEventEmitter,1);

// Create a handler (Listener?):
  
const handleMyEvent = (data) => {
    console.log('Was fired: ', data);
};

console.log(handleMyEvent,2);

// Add it to the instance:

myEventEmitter.on('EventOne', handleMyEvent);
myEventEmitter.on('EventTwo', handleMyEvent);
console.log(myEventEmitter);

// Finally, emit an event:

myEventEmitter.emit('EventOne', 'hi');
myEventEmitter.emit('EventTwo', 'good day!');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_events` property is an object indexed by event name. When `.on` is called, a listener is added into an array at that name. For example, doing

```
ee.on('theEvent', () => console.log('foo'))
```

results in the following structure:

```
{
  _events: {
    theEvent: [
      () => console.log('foo')
    ]
  }
}
```

The `emit` method iterates over all listeners for a given event name. If the first argument - the event name - was `theEvent`, then the code would do

```
this._events[name].forEach(fireCallbacks);
// equivalent to
this._events.theEvent.forEach(fireCallbacks);
```

iterating over the array at `theEvent`.

For each item in the array, it then runs the `forEach` callback:

```
(callback) => callback(data);
```

The first argument to the `forEach` callback is the item being iterated over - so that's the `callback` variable. `callback(data)` then invokes the array item being iterated over (eg `() => console.log('foo')` from earlier) and passes it a `data` argument.